# Plot gvisMotionChart with timevar as month and year

Tags: r, googlevis

I have a data frame `df` with a column

```
df$year_month = "2011-1" "2011-02" "2011-03" ...
```

I wanted to use this as the `timevar` argument of the `gvisMotionChart` function. I tried:

```
library(zoo)
df$year_month = as.yearmon(df$year_month)
```

However, when I tried plotting the graph, I received the following error:

> The timevar has to be of numeric or Date format. Currently is it
>   yearmon

When plotting `gvisMotionChart` is it possible to have the time variable displaying the values:

```
"Jan 2011" "Feb 2011" ...
```

As Roland suggests, I could convert to numeric e.g. `201101, 201102, ...` but then presumably the time variable would display the values:

```
"201101" "201102" ...
```

Comment: Isn't it obvious from the error message? Make `df$year_month` a numeric or Date.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using class "yearmon" you need to use class "Date":

```
df$date <- as.Date(paste0(df$year_month,"-1"),format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Then you can use the `date.format` parameter of `gvisMotionChart`.

From the help page:

```
M3 <- gvisMotionChart(Fruits, "Fruit", "Date", date.format="%YW%W")
```

Comment: thanks Roland. this looks good. what would the date format be to get the time variable running over months (as opposed to weeks which it currently does)?